# Getting missing script: start error in npm

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I get this error when I run `npm start`.

> ```
> npm ERR! Missing script: "start"  
> npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
> npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
> npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
> npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
> npm ERR!   npm run
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-28T13_04_19_260Z-debug.log
> ```

Comment: it is probably something like npm *run* start.
otherwise check your package.json file, under the property script it shows you the available scripts for the project

Comment: Edit your question to include your package.json and read [the docs for npm start](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-start) where it says you need a `start` script like `"scripts": { "start": "node foo.js" }`

Answer (score 1):

`package.json` has various sections, `scripts` is one of them, which allows you to write npm scripts which we can run using `npm run <script-name>`. The error you're getting is because your `start` script is missing in that section.

For a node app, your `package.json` file should look similar to this.

```json
{
    "name": "server",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "app.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.3"
    }
}
```

In the above code, focus on the `scripts` section. The following line is missing in your `package.json` file.

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
},
```

Add this line and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

- Option_1:    Control inside file "package.json":

```
"scripts": {            
    "start": "what command is here?",                  
    },
```

- Option_2:    Control Terminal (folder) where you write command OR open the responding terminal for your project: right-click
  on the project name -> "Open in integrated Terminal"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I had the "start" script and everything should have worked, but it didn't.
What actually helped me eventually was just saving the changes, ctrl+s.
That's it, I just had to save changes and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me and my package.json was correct. My fix was that I had something running on port 3000 & didn't realize it.

1. I used the debugger on the "start" code line under "Scripts" in the package.json
2. It told me something was already running on port 3000 then asked "
   Would you like to run the app on another port instead? (Y/N)
3. I click my "Y" key - the debugger compiled and opened my app on port 3001
4. Form I was trying to render loaded perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Do you have put node on Firewall settings public an private network

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you are facing this issue for the react after creating the react app then always check for the folder are you in is correct or not .....? run `cd "project name"` and try `npm start` command again

Answer (score -1):

You have to put what command you need npm to run when you give npm start.

[image]

You have to write node index.js in scripts.start in your package.json file